# How can I build an FAQ Page with sections?

Tags: 8

I am seeking to build an FAQ page that covers a few different types of topics, thus creating a need for sections, preferably with links. Like below:

[image: An FAQ page with sections.]

I am using Drupal 8 and have the [FAQ Field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/faqfield) installed. I'm having trouble creating a content type since I cannot add the FAQ Field multiple times to the same content type. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you add the FAQ Field to multiple content types? It is just a field type so adding it to content or entity types should work. Are you saying it does not appear in the list of existing fields?

Comment: I can add it to multiple content types, but I can't add it multiple times to the same content type. Sorry, should have been more clear.

Comment: Possibly Double field can handle this.
https://www.drupal.org/files/double_field_faq.png

Comment: By "Double field" I think @ya.teck means changing the field settings to allow "Multiple Values". This would work well for multiple FAQ items, but not sections. You should not have any trouble adding a **new field** of FAQ Field type to the same content type. Are you attempting to add the same field instance to the content type? This is not possible. But it does not matter because you can create a new field instance with a different name e.g. field_faq_general, field_faq_printing, field_faq_binding,n etc...

Comment: Sounds like Paragraphs could be a way to solve that. FAQ Paragraph with a heading field, content reference field (to FAQ entity/content type). There are a few recipes you could do to solve this, really up to the implementor as to what works for them. That way they are not limited by section name and having to create a field-per-section. Just a thought. A reason for FAQ as a type and reference field would be for reusable FAQ lists, made possible with Paragraphs of different configurations. I just did something similar for flexibility for the client.

Comment: I've tried @mradcliffe's idea and that works for me. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the [FAQ Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/faqfield) module, you may want to use the [Views Accordion](http://drupal.org/project/views_accordion) module instead (for which an official release for D8 is already available), and its related [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/366263).

By "grouping fields", the group header can be used as accordion header. In your case, just use your "*Sections*" (like General, Printing, Binding) as those grouping fields. Obviously, you'd have to have a regular field (like a select list field) to actually indicate for each question in your FAQ what the actual Section for it should be.

With this approach, you have the full power of Views available to make your FAQ look like you'd want it to look.

Answer (score 0):

Using the paragraphs module:

1) Add a "faq_question_answer" paragraph type with a field_question and a field_answer field

2) If you would like to be able to add FAQS to multiple pages, you can add an "faq" paragraph type with a paragraph field on it referencing your "faq_question_answer" paragraph type.  Then you can add this to an existing paragraph field on a node type as an option for the types of paragraphs you can add.

3) Alternatively you could just add a "field_faq" to a content type that references the faq_question_answer paragraph type.

4) If you would like groups of questions and answers (such as in the screenshot in the question) that are grouped by topic, you can either add separate fields for each topic on a content type, or you can add a topic taxonomy field to the "faq" paragraph type, and then have a field_faqs on your content type that allows adding multiple faq paragraphs each with a selected topic that would display as the header of that section.